# How to detect triangular shaped traffic sign using Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a code snippet to detect shape of traffic signs. The code works reasonably well for detecting shapes except for triangular shaped traffic signs. I tried tuning the value (i.e 0.01) to second parameter of the function cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * peri, True) but I am not able to find the right value.

I tried tuning the value (i.e 0.01) to second parameter of the function cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * peri, True) but I am not able to find the right value.

```
 from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import cv2
myPath = '/home/raghu/Downloads/SSIMProject/ImageData/sample'
files = [ f for f in listdir(myPath) if isfile(join(myPath, f))]
for eachFile in files:
    img = cv2.imread(join(myPath, eachFile), 1)
    cv2.imshow('img1', img[:,:,0])
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img[:,:,0], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
    for cnt in contours:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.0112 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
        print(len(approx))
        if len(approx) == 8:
            print("Octagon")
            cv2.putText(img, 'Octagon', (10, 30), font, 0.3, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif len(approx) == 7:
            print("Heptagon")
            cv2.putText(img, 'Heptagon', (10, 30), font, 0.3, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif len(approx) == 6:
            print("Hexagon")
            cv2.putText(img, 'Hexagon', (10, 30), font, 0.3, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif len(approx) == 5:
            print("Pentagon")
            cv2.putText(img, 'Pentagon', (10, 30), font, 0.3, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif len(approx) == 4:
            print("Square")
            cv2.putText(img, 'Square', (10, 30), font, 0.3, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        elif len(approx) == 3:
            print("Triangle")
            cv2.putText(img, 'Triangle', (10, 30), font, 0.3, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        else:
            print("Circle")
            cv2.putText(img, 'Circle', (10, 30), font, 0.3, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('sign', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect the triangular shaped traffic signs to be detected.

Comment: show your raw img, thresh1 image and controu image so that other can help you determine the cause of not able to detect

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code that will help you detect triangle in an image 
once you that you can create a color filter based on the color of the traffic triangle such as a red filter and then use that so that it always detect the red sign only

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX

img = cv2.imread("shapes.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0), 5)
    x = approx.ravel()[0]
    y = approx.ravel()[1]
cv2.putText(img, "Triangle", (x, y), font, 1, (0))
cv2.imshow("shapes", img)
cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshold)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```